# Regular Expression to match the sequence pattern

Tags: regex, perl

I am trying to use reg ex to carve the hex contents of a jpg file from a drive.

Is there a way that I could search for a value that starts with "ffd8" and ends with "ffd9" (allowing anything in between except a repeating "ffd8" sequence)?

For example, this would be a match:
**ffd80123456789abcdffd9**

Although it would only match last pairing "ffd8" characters through "ffd9":

ffd8zxywffd80123456789abcdffd9** -> ignore the first ffd8zxyw and match ffd80123456789abcdffd9

Is there a way that regular expression could do this?

Thank you

Comment: @GrijeshChauhan `ffd8.*?ffd9` to keep it non-greedy ;-)

Comment: @hjpotter92 you are correct.

Comment: What are you using to write/run this regex?

Comment: Thanks for the fast reply, I tried both although they match the first occurrence of ""ffd8". Is there a way that it can only match the last occurrence of "ffd8" instead? (as a way to make sure that the jpg file header is not included twice) http://regex101.com/r/eG0bD2

Comment: @ClickRick I am using this regex in a perl script

Comment: In which case I'd suggest adding the perl tag to the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Perl regular expression `ffd8(?:(?!ffd8).)*ffd9` matches just **ffd80123456789abcdffd9** of string `ffd8zxywffd80123456789abcdffd9`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the greedy match at the beginning of the expression:

```
.*(ffd8(.*)ffd9)
```

[image: Regular expression visualization]

You can see it at [work here](http://regex101.com/r/xL6xM5). Note that I am not using the `U` modifier.